# Why do radio stations have ranges

Tags: electromagnetism, wavelength, radio-frequency

If you have been on a long car ride you would know that the signal of a radio station becomes weaker and weaker and then stops. But since radio waves are just a wavelength of the electromagnetic spectrum and these don't really have a maximum limit they can travel why does this happen?

Comment: Correction, radio waves and light are both wavelengths of the [electromagnetic spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum)

Comment: *"light doesn't have a range"* - not sure what you mean by this; the propagating electromagnetic fields go as $\frac{1}{r}$.  However, there's another aspect affecting radio reception which is that the surface of the Earth is curved.

Answer (score 2):

Technically (ideally), radio waves, and all other electromagnetic waves, do go out forever without stopping, just like any massive object would. The difference between a wave and an object is that a wave expands in every direction from its source. However, conservation of energy says the wave can neither lose nor gain energy. To compensate for the wave's increased surface area as it travels further from its source (picture the wave front as an expanding sphere), the energy per unit area of the wave must decrease, to maintain a constant total energy.

More precisely, if an electromagnetic wave carries some amount of energy "E", and the wave has traveled a distance "r" from its source, the energy per unit area "u" anywhere on the wave will be its total energy divided by its total surface area: $u = \frac{E}{4\pi r^2}$ 
You can see from the equation that the energy per unit area carried by the wave is inversely proportional to the square of its distance from the source, while the total energy carried by the wave remains the same.

Comment: This is right, though I suspect in most cases the curvature of the Earth gets in the way before the signal gets that weak. On a perfectly spherical Earth, the tallest building in the world can only be seen about 70 km away; beyond that it is below the horizon.

Comment: Shorter radio waves (e.g. FM radio at 90-108MHz, or around 3 meters) is basically line-of-sight, but longer waves (e.g. AM radio at 550-1600kHz, or 550-190 meters) diffract along the surface of the Earth, and thus reach further.

Comment: Yeah the line of sight is not a limiting factor for all radio waves. Some AM waves also reflects on the ionosphere (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skywave) allowing to overcome the line of sight.

Comment: This communication method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_burst_communications uses brief moments of enhanced atmospheric reflectivity from meteor trails!